# Why does the z change when I move this cube? [c#][Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am really new to unity so I wanted to make a simple 2d project where you can move a cube. So I made a script to move the cube but when I play the game the Z changes along with the X so it will fall of the map.

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9oHSc6dN2A&feature=youtu.be

The script I'm using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector2 input;

    public float movementSpeed = 50f;
    private float horizontal;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

        rigidbody.AddForce ((Vector2.right * movementSpeed) * horizontal);
    }
}
```

I am using unity 4

Comment: Is there friction involved or more physics? Do the rigidbodies have some physic-materials attached to them? You could try and replace the `AddForce()` call with a `transform.position = transform.position + movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime * horizontal * Vector2.right;`. Rotation of both the floor and cube are zeroed out? Sounds like physics inaccuracies which come from applying force on the rigidbody.

Comment: Is `rigidbody` of type [Rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) or [Rigidbody2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html)? According to [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_Vector2.html) Vector2 can be implicitly cast to Vector3, which may cause undesired behavior in the `Z` direction when using the 3D `Rigidbody` and adding forces.

Comment: @Quantic Hmm...although a `Vector2` can be cast to a `Vector3`, the docs also state that the z-value is set to zero (so it shouldn't lead to a force applied along the z-axis). I don't have much of an idea why this is happening either - a workaround for the OP would be to freeze Z translation on the Rigidbody, though it'd still leave the mystery unsolved.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt These are all the settings: http://prntscr.com/al5tqd I have use gravity enabled.

Comment: @Quantic I think it is a normal Rigidbody.

Comment: @J.Doe If you never plan on using the z-axis, you can lock it by checking off Freeze Position Z - so physical interactions will not affect position along the z-axis. Alternatively, there's some other options: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/20694/2d-locking-the-z-axis.html

Comment: @Serlite Thanks for your answer I will do that but is this normal or not?

Comment: @J.Doe Only thing I can think of is that this may be due to a friction error, as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042690/collision-on-x-axis-means-0-movement-in-y-axis). You can try testing it by placing a Physics material with 0 friction on the colliding objects and seeing if the problem persists.

Comment: for goodness sake men.  OP is just asking for the "constraint" toggles in rigidbod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rigidbody has `Use Gravity` checked. Romove that and it should function the way you want. [Wrong axis]

Edit:

A Rigidbody has a constraint property. Freeze z position there.

[image]

Comment: Yes i know but I wan't there to be gravity :p

Comment: Ah, was getting the wrong impression of the axis. See my edit.

Comment: @GunnarB. you can add a lot of charm to your great answers, using the "bendy arrows" now on offer in damned `Preview` - here I've matched the jaunty color of the local up-vote arrow.

Comment: @JoeBlow Oh, nice, I didn't know about those!

Comment: @JoeBlow Actually, need to come back to that: Is that arrow made here as option of SO or is that done with an image processing software? Couldn't find how to do that.

Comment: ah it's only, if you have a Mac it's built-in to the little app where you open PNGs ("preview").  Cheers!

Comment: @JoeBlow Ah, too bad, but I would have to save a screenshot with some software anyways, so I can do that too.